# What is non overloaded pointer to member and overloaded pointer to member?

Tags: c++

I am reading C++ programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup. I came across the statement in templates section.

A template argument can be a constant expression (§C.5), the address of an object or function
with external linkage (§9.2), or a non overloaded pointer to member (§15.5).

What is non overloaded pointer to member? Can someone give example?

Comment: Looks like he references 15.5...

Comment: Just FYI, pointers to members are not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A non-overloaded pointer-to-member is as the name states -- *a pointer to a member that hasn't overloaded a superclass*. Here's an example I've just put together of what will and won't work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void printN() { std::cout << 42; }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    void printN() { std::cout << 31; }
};

template <typename T, typename C>
class SomeTemplate {
public:
    void PrintData(T d) { C c; (c.*d)(); }
};

int main() {
    SomeTemplate<void (Foo::*) (), Foo> t; // Compiles - '42'
    t.PrintData(&Foo::printN);

    SomeTemplate<void (Bar::*) (), Bar> t; // Compiles - '31'
    t.PrintData(&Bar::printN);

    SomeTemplate<void (Foo::*) (), Bar> t; // Won't compile, can't convert overloaded pointers
    t.PrintData(&Foo::printN);
    return 0;
}
```

In PrintData, an instance of the class is created and the member pointer passed is dereferenced on  the instantiated version of the class, resulting in it's underlying function being called.

Templates make this approach somewhat more flexible, but I've yet to find a reason to use code such as this in a real situation however -- if anyone can find a one I'd love to be enlightened..

Comment: Do you know of an example where an overloaded pointer to member isn't valid?

Comment: This doesn't use a PTM value as a template argument, this uses a PTM type. As I read the question, it's about PTM values.

Comment: @VaughnCato I've just modified the example to incorporate this. @hvd I haven't yet been able to compile the use of a PTM value as a template argument (i.e `Template<Foo::printN>`)- how would you go about that syntactically?